# Internationalizing whole text with markup in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, translation

What's the best practice for internationalizing, say, a Terms of Service document in Rails 3? I can think of two options:

- Creating a partial for each locale and choosing which one to load according to the current user's locale.
- `<li><%= I18n.t :tos_paragraph_1 %></li><li><%= I18n.t :tos_paragraph_2 %></li>`

None of these seems like a good solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a partial for each language is definitly undry.

The Rails way is the second option you suggest with a .yml for each language.

The doc provides great examples to let you organize the yml according to each page. Thus you have shortcuts for all your variables.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: Are you sure about that? It's an ugly solution. It's hard to believe Rails wants me to go with it.

Comment: I do :) its not ugly at all, you call variables defined precuse yml files, it's just clean. Just use the shortcut in views: I18n.t becomes t

Comment: Well, I was looking for a better solution than that. It just seems lame to have a string for each paragraph.

Comment: Ok I see, be aware that you can add html in the yml file. And render it properly with 'raw'. So one variable in the yml could represent a big paragraph with whatever style you need.

Comment: Oh, that sounds interesting. Pardon my ignorance, what's that «rendering it with raw» thing?

Comment: Just <%=raw t :your_var %> this way html is interpreted.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few solutions, but if I were doing this for a production project, I would probably do something like the following:

1. Create files for your translated Terms of Services in `config/locales/terms/`, naming them `terms.en.html`, replacing `en` with the locale for each translation and `html` with the format of the file (e.g. you could use Haml, Markdown, etc.).
2. Create the following helper methods (put them in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` to use them everywhere, but you can put them in whatever helper file you need/want):

   ```
   def localized_document_for(document, locale)
     raise ArgumentError.new('nil is not a valid document') if document.nil?
     raise I18n::InvalidLocale.new('nil is not a valid locale') if locale.nil?
     localized_document = path_for_localized_document(document, locale)
     raise MissingTranslationData unless File.exists?(localized_document)
     # If you're using Markdown, etc. replace with code to parse/format your document
     File.open(localized_document).readlines.join
   end

   def path_for_localized_document(document, locale)
     "#{Rails.root}/config/locales/#{document}/#{document}.#{locale.to_s}.html"
   end
   ```

Now, in your views, you can use `localized_document_for('terms', I18n.locale)` any time you need to get the contents of the Terms of Service in the user's language. Now the code you're using to fetch the document is DRY (you can easily fetch other documents by creating another directory in `config/locales` and changing the value of the `document` argument), and your translated documents are stored in their own directory and can easily be edited (and don't depend on YAML, which brings no value to storing a single document in a file).

Note that if you wanted to do it the "Rails 3 Way," you could use the `I18n::Backend::Chain` (see https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/chain.rb), and pass in `I18n::Backend::Simple.new` along with a custom backend that reads the files as necessary, but for a one-off deal I believe the helpers work sufficiently.

Comment: File.open(localized_document).readlines.join doesn't work in my rails 3.2 app. I replace it with this instead: render :file => localized_document