# i18n markdown files in Rails 3 views

Tags: internationalization, haml, markdown, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I am currently working through Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2) while experimenting with some other things not covered in the book.  After completing [Chapter 5](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout?version=3.2#top), where the static pages are created, I decided change the view code to HAML, internationalize the pages, and put the static content into separate (non-partial) Markdown files, using the RDiscount gem to render them.  For example:

**app/views/static_pages/about.html.haml**

```
- provide(:title, t('.about_us'))
:markdown
  #{render file: "static_pages/about.#{params[:locale]}.md"}
```

Under the **static_pages** directory, I have Markdown files like **about.en.md**, **about.it.md**, **about.ja.md** etc, so interpolating in the `:locale` parameter is what determines which language Markdown file gets rendered.

My questions are:

1. The **static_pages** directory is a bit crowded with Markdown files, so are there any sensible default/best practice locations (perhaps outside of the **app** directory) to keep these Markdown files, where they could be presumably be edited by people who don't need to know about the inner workings of the app?
2. What better ways are there to implement rendering multi-lingual Markdown files in views?  My use of `:locale` and the double string-interpolation seems inelegant.
3. Is there a way to change this code so that I can pass Ruby variables into the Markdown file?  I know I can, for example, use a `#{language}` variable in the Markdown by just changing **about.en.md** into a HAML partial (**_about.en.html.haml**) and change the code to look something like:

   **app/views/static_pages/about.html.haml**

   ```
   - provide(:title, t('.about_us'))
   :markdown
     #{render "about.#{params[:locale]}", language: 'Markdown!'}
   ```

   But, is there a way to do this without changing the Markdown file into another type of file?  If such a way exists, is it recommended/feasible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After having a look at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901393/567863), it seemed that the best location for i18n Markdown files would be their own action name directories under the **config/locales** directory, and that there was a good opportunity to refactor the `render` code on all views for the `StaticPagesController`.  So, using **about.html.haml** as an example below, the call to `render` in the **home**, **help**, **about**, and **contact** views has been changed to the exact same code:

**app/views/static_pages/about.html.haml**

```
- provide(:title, t('.about_us'))
:markdown
  #{render file: localized_page_for(action_name, params[:locale])}
```

The `localized_page_for` method is defined in the `StaticPagesHelper`:

**app/helpers/static_pages_helper.rb**

```
module StaticPagesHelper
  def localized_page_for(action, locale)
    "#{Rails.root}/config/locales/#{action}/#{action}.#{locale.to_s}.md"
  end
end
```

So, now all the Markdown files have been taken out of the **app/views/static_pages** directory and are called from their respective logical directories (eg. **config/locales/about/about.en.md** etc) using `ActionController`'s `action_name` attribute and the locale, making for less clutter.

As for question 2 above, string-interpolation seems to be common enough for this kind of problem, so I'll consider it "elegant" enough as well.

As for question 3 above, after exhaustive searching, I haven't found a way anyone has passed in variables in to a pure Markdown file, and [the documentation](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) doesn't seem to say anything about supporting them, so I'm going to conclude that it's not possible.  If passing Ruby variables in to Markdown is absolutely necessary, the file will need to be run through another interpreter, kind of like is described in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10061808/567863).

#### **Update:**

After running security scanner [Brakeman](http://brakemanscanner.org/) against the app, it came up with a potential [Dynamic Render Path](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/dynamic_render_path/) security warning (albeit a weak one) due to dynamically passing in `params[:locale]` to the `render` call instead of passing it a static string.  So, I moved the call to the `localized_page` method out of the views, moved the method itself out of the `StaticPagesHelper` (so that file is now empty) and in to the `StaticPagesController` and then instantiated a `@page` instance variable in each method to pass to the view.  In summary, the code now looks like this, which doesn't get the security warning:

**app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :localized_page, only: [:help, :about, :contact]

  def home
    if signed_in?
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    else
      localized_page
    end
  end

 def help
 end

 def about
 end

 def contact  
 end

 private

   def localized_page
    @page = "#{Rails.root}/config/locales/"\
            "#{action_name}/#{action_name}.#{params[:locale].to_s}.md"
   end
end
```

**app/views/static_pages/about.html.haml**

```
- provide(:title, t('.about_us'))
:markdown
  #{render file: @page}
```