# i18n formatted text

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, internationalization, i18n-gem

I have a question regarding the best practise of handling formated text when using i18n. For example, let say I have a *about us* page with multiple paragraphs, bullet points etc. (keeping in mind that I dont want to change the template directly every time I add a paragraph or bullet pint)
How am I best representing these more complicated structures? Are they at all possible to do with i18n or should I be using a different technique?

Comment: a piece of source code would be good, and explain what exactly you want to do to wich part of the text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal preference is to store content in Markdown within an I18n string.

Comment: I second use of Markdown.  [This Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10233686/567863) may also be of reference to you, vincent.